# HttpClient and Exception Handling

Tags: c#, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, cancellation

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

try
{

    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);


     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
        // do something
     }

}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    // do error stuff
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    // do error stuff #2
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do error stuff #3
}
```

I am new to HttpClient.

During our test, we shut down the web service that this code is hitting in order to test this block of code.  (BTW, it works as expected when the web service is running.)

Why does it take 2 minutes and 10 sec instead of 30 seconds to hit the `TaskCanceledException` catch?

Comment: Shouldn't `client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);` be at least before `client.PostAsync`?

Comment: You have to set the timeout before calling `PostAsync`. The timeout will affect any subsequent requests; requests already in flight will use whatever setting was in place when they were started.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo on my part when I was transcribing.  I corrected it.

Comment: If I use just the following, it does time out after 30 seconds:

`HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`

Comment: if I modified the original code and remove `httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };`, it doesn't time out after 30 seconds.  So it has to do with passing the `HttpClientHandler`?

Comment: No, the default timeout is 100 seconds.

Comment: I agree.  That is why I posted the question.  A sample project work as expect.

Answer (score 1):

[The default timeout for HttpClient is 100 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/httpclient/httpclient-timeout-method). The observed 130 seems pretty strange.

If you run the following code inside dotnet fiddle, then you would see it does cancel the request after 2 seconds and will not wait for a response for 5 seconds:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://httpstat.us");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        try 
        {
            _ = await client.GetAsync("/200?sleep=5000");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            "Timed out".Dump();
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
        "Finished".Dump();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree.  I created a sample project and it timed out after 30 seconds.  Not sure what is in the existing project that could be causing the issue.

Comment: @KT-Guy What kind of project are we talking about? .NET Fw / .NET Core / .NET? Console / WinService / ASP.NET / other?

Comment: I added back the HttpClientHandler and it times out after about 130 seconds in my sample. https://github.com/KT-Guy/Xamarin/issues/1

Comment: @KT-Guy Thanks for the link, I will check it on Monday.

Comment: @KT-Guy Are you saying that whenever you are using a custom handler where you set the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` then it will timeout in 130 seconds but when you don't it will timeout in 30 seconds?

Comment: That’s is correct.

Comment: @KT-Guy Could you please check this:https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/59050 ?

Comment: Thanks.  I read it but not sure if it is related. I observed the 130 seconds on the first try.  Their issue seems to be keeping the connection open.